# c# - DataContext disposed in ASP.NET Core scheduler

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have included Coravel scheduler in my ASP.NET application.

Everything seems to work well, but when the scheduler starts running it returns System.ObjectDisposedException on the DataContext. 
I use Dependency Injection in my repository classes, does the context only get created when it receives a request from the browser?
How can I fix this so the context is available when my scheduler runs the method?

Below is my repository code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Project.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;


namespace Project.Data.CustomerRepo
{
    public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        public CustomerRepository(DataContext context)
        {
            this._context = context;

        }
        public async Task<Customer> Create(Customer customer)
        {
            await _context.Customers.AddAsync(customer);
            return customer;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> Create(IEnumerable<Customer> customers)
        {
            await _context.Customers.AddRangeAsync(customers);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return customers;
        }

        public async Task Delete(Customer customer)
        {
            _context.Customers.Remove(customer);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task<Customer> Read(int id)
        {
            var customer = await _context.Customers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(customerItem => customerItem.Id == id);
            return customer;
        }
        public async Task<Customer> ReadFromFacebookId(string id)
        {
            var customer = await _context.Customers.Where(customerItem => customerItem.FacebookId == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            return customer;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> Read()
        {
            var customers = await _context.Customers.ToListAsync();
            return customers;
        }

        public async Task<Customer> Update(Customer customer)
        {
            _context.Update(customer);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return customer;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`services.AddDbContext<>()`registers the `DataContext` as a service with `ServiceLifetime.Scoped` which means that your `DataContext` is created per web request. It is disposed when request is completed.

You could inject `IServiceScopeFactory` which is singleton into your controller/repository, then create a new scope using `CreateScope()` and request the `DataContext` service from that scope

```
public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory
    public CustomerRepository(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }
    public async Task<Customer> Create(Customer customer)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();              
            await context.Customers.AddAsync(customer);
            return customer;
        }

        return customer;

    }
}
```

Refer to [Access DbContext service from background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572637/access-dbcontext-service-from-background-task)

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. Your reference also explained about IHostedService which is a better alternative than the library I was using!