# ASP.NET Core Web App DI Error - Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am creating a ASP.NET Core web application. I am using a Repository through a library project. I reference it in the web application project.

The repository interface is as below:

```
public interface IPushNotificationRepository
{
    IQueryable<PushNotification> Notifications
    {
        get;
    }
    IQueryable<Client> Clients
    {
        get;
    }

    void Add(PushNotification notification);
    void Add(Client client);
    void AddRange(IList<PushNotification> notifications);
    bool AddIfNotAlreadySent(PushNotification notification);
    void UpdateDelivery(PushNotification notification);
    bool CheckIfClientExists(string client);
    Client FindClient(int? id);
    void Update(Client client);
    void Delete(Client client);
}
```

Within the repository I inject the db context

```
    public class PushNotificationRepository : IPushNotificationRepository
    {
        private readonly PushNotificationsContext _context;

        public PushNotificationRepository(PushNotificationsContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
}
```

The configure services of the start up class is as below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddSingleton<IPushNotificationRepository, PushNotificationRepository>();
    services.AddDbContextPool<PushNotificationsContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PushNotificationsConnection")));
}
```

In the controller class I consume the repository:

```
    public class ClientsController : Controller
    {
        //private readonly PushNotificationsContext _context;
        private readonly IPushNotificationRepository _pushNotificationRepository;

        public ClientsController(IPushNotificationRepository pushNotificationRepository)
        {
            _pushNotificationRepository = pushNotificationRepository;
        }
}
```

The repository classes are in a separate library project which is referenced by the web application project. The error I receive is:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be
>   constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
>   'ServiceType:
>   Services.Messaging.Data.Abstract.IPushNotificationRepository Lifetime:
>   Singleton ImplementationType:
>   Services.Messaging.Data.PushNotificationRepository': Cannot consume
>   scoped service 'Services.Messaging.Data.PushNotificationsContext' from
>   singleton
>   'Services.Messaging.Data.Abstract.IPushNotificationRepository'.)'

Would really appreciate some advise on this

Comment: Change `services.AddSingleton<IPushNotificationRepository, PushNotificationRepository>();` to `services.AddScoped<IPushNotificationRepository, PushNotificationRepository>();`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A singleton cannot reference a Scoped instance. The error message is clear.

> Cannot consume scoped service
>   'Services.Messaging.Data.PushNotificationsContext' from singleton

PushNotificationsContext is considered as a scoped service. You should almost never consume scoped service or transient service from a singleton. You should also avoid consuming transient service from a scoped service. Consuming scoped services it's a good practice to inject what you need, it gets cleaned up after the request automatically.

Either

> services.AddTransient < IPushNotificationRepository, PushNotificationRepository>();

or

> services.AddScoped< IPushNotificationRepository, PushNotificationRepository>();

will work fine, but check your design. Maybe this is not the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. I did not know that the DbContext is always going to be injected as a scope. This fixed the issue as I complete all required work within the Controller request lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

`services.AddDbContext<PushNotificationsContext>()` registers the `PushNotificationsContext` as a service with `ServiceLifetime.Scoped` which means that your `PushNotificationsContext` is created per web request. It is disposed when request is completed.

You could inject `IServiceScopeFactory` which is singleton into your repository, then create a new scope using `CreateScope()` and request the `PushNotificationsContext` service from that scope

```
public class PushNotificationRepository : IPushNotificationRepository
{
    IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
    public PushNotificationRepository(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public void Add(PushNotification notification);
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PushNotificationsContext>();
            //other logic
        }


    }
}
```

Refer to [c# - DataContext disposed in ASP.NET Core scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022540/c-sharp-datacontext-disposed-in-asp-net-core-scheduler/59024578#59024578)

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation and for the link explaining the long running worker implementation. Got a idea on how it should be implemented as well. In my scenario, I am completing all the tasks within the controller lifetime. Thanks again !

Comment: @sm101 You are welcome.Could you accept the answer if you have resolved the problem?If you have any other question, you could post a new thread.