# DbContext disposes randomly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have an azure function that read from an azure Queue, but for some reason, in my DbContext, Change Tracking Disposes itself and I can't figure out why...

I am injecting my context into my class (being called from my function), so my code looks like this

```
public class ProcessQueue
{
    private readonly ILogger<ProcessQueue> _logger;
    private readonly IHelperClass _helperClass;

    public ProcessQueue(
        ILogger<ProcessQueue> logger,
        IHelperClass helperClass)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _helperClass= helperClass;
    }

    [Function("ProcessQueue")]
    [QueueOutput("queue")]
    public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("queue", Connection = "StorageConnectionString:queue")] HelperObj helperObj)
    {

        _helperClass.ProcessQueue(helperObj);
    }
}

public class HelperClass : IHelperClass
{
        private readonly BlobContainerClient _blobContainerClient;
        private EntityContext _entityContext;

 public async Task ProcessQueue(HelperObj helperObj) 
 {
     // Fetch Candidate
     var object = _entityContext.Objects
         .Where(x => x.Id == helperObj.Id)
         .FirstOrDefault();

     // BackupData
     await this.SaveData(helperObj.data);

     CallContextForSomeReason();
 }

 private async Task Save(
     Stream data) 
 {
     await _blobContainerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

     await _blobContainerClient.UploadBlobAsync("test.xlsx",data);
 }

public bool CallContextForSomeReason()
{
    bool exists = _entityContext.AnotherObj.Any(x => x.Id == 1);

    return exists;
}
}
```

The code above is just for demonstration only so I can get across how my methods are interacting with eachother. The main issue here is by the time I call Any() on the context, the ChangeTracker has been disposed for whatever reason but this is causing me an issue

DI Config:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        var configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
        var dbConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DbConnection");
        var settings = configuration.Get<Settings>();

        services.AddDbContext<DbContext, EntityContext>(options =>
                options.UseNpgsql(dbConnectionString, o => o.UseNetTopologySuite())
                .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention()
                .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information));
        
        ...
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Comment: share your dependency injection configuration

Comment: @DanielA.White Just updated the question (I think that is what you meant?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access DbContext service from background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572637/access-dbcontext-service-from-background-task)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to unawaited code. If you define methods as `async`, you need to await them. Otherwise a web request will finish and the IoC container will dispose references when the lifetime scope associated to the request is disposed. Looking at your example, I see one case with ProcessQueue not being awaited:

```
[Function("ProcessQueue")]
[QueueOutput("queue")]
public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("queue", Connection = "StorageConnectionString:queue")] HelperObj helperObj)
{

    await _helperClass.ProcessQueue(helperObj); // <- Await your async....
}
```

You should go through your code and check for all `async` methods then make sure they are awaited where you call them.

It is good practice to suffix `async` methods with "Async"  (ProcessQueueAsync) as a reminder to await them as a default course of action. The only situation that an async method would not awaited is when you want to parallelize with a 'WaitAll()' but in the case of working with EF, only so long as they (`async` methods) scope their own individual `DbContext`.

Comment: That's amazing thank you! I had read that could be the issue but couldn't figure out where I had missed await as the error was in the helper class! I feel so stupid but thanks loads!