# C# EF get DbContext outside of WebApplication

Tags: c#, web-applications, entity-framework-core

first of all my program:
I have a console application which starts a thread and a webapplication.

The thread is receiving events and has to validate and insert some things in the database. The webapplication receives api calls and has to have access to the database aswell, validating and inserting. Both are communicating between each other aswell.

My problem now is that I'm not really understanding a good way to use the DbContext in both "applications".

I've tried to receive the DbContext inside the thread from the webapplication via:

```
app.Services.GetService<DbContext>();
```

This doesn't work and just freezes the thread.

Is it an acceptable way to DI in webapplication in controllers and use this is the thread?

```
using(var context = new DbContext())
```

I'm just thinking if there is a better way to not always create a new connection and use the same dbcontext as in the webapplication.

This is my DbContext

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionstring);
    }

    public DbSet<Class> Name { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Class> Name { get; set; }
}
```

I hope you guys could understand me, my english isn't the best.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read and help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access DbContext service from background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572637/access-dbcontext-service-from-background-task)

Comment: "A DbContext instance is designed to be used for a single unit-of-work. This means that the lifetime of a DbContext instance is usually very short."

Comment: @GerrySchmitz So it is a good way to use "using(var context = new DbContext())" in my thread?

Comment: @Myridor The point is: a dbContext is "lightweight", and there is no penalty creating them as you need them. And yes, "using" insures each "instance" of dbContext get disposed when you're done with it (to avoid memory leaks).

Comment: Opening your own threads is not a good practice. Let's see your code. When done properly, you should just be able to inject the context same as in the web application.