# Dependency Injection on static method in ASP .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have registered the implementation of my logger in ServiceCollection in the start up:

```cs
services.AddTransient(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(GenericLogger<>));
```

Usually, I do this to inject using Constructor:

```cs
class DynamoEventProcessor
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    private readonly IDogStatsd _dogStatsd;
    private readonly ILogger<DynamoEventProcessor> _logger;

    public DynamoEventProcessor(IRepository repository, IDogStatsd dogStatsd, ILogger<DynamoEventProcessor> logger)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _dogStatsd = dogStatsd;
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

But I have a class where there is no constructor:

```cs
public class ProfileContent
{
    public MemoryStream Content { get; set; }
    public string ContentAlgorithm { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>> DataKeys { get; set; }
    public long ExpiresUtc { get; set; }
    public long Version { get; set; }
    public long Deleted { get; set; }

    public static Dictionary<string, EncryptedDataAndKeys> GetEncryptedDataAndKeys(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>> profileContentAttributes)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Available Keys: " + KeysAsString(keyList));
        _logger.LogInformation("AccountId missing Coporate Data: " + _converter.GetValueFromAttributeValue(attributes["AccountId"]).ToString());
        var encryptedDataAndKeys = new Dictionary<string, EncryptedDataAndKeys>();

        foreach (var item in profileContentAttributes)
        {
            encryptedDataAndKeys.Add(item.Key, GetEncryptedDataAndKey(item.Value));
        }

        return encryptedDataAndKeys;
    }
}
```

My `_logger` failed here due to null. I understand the problem, that I didn't inject it properly. How can I inject it when I use it in static method without instantiating an object?

Comment: I would make the static method a service (probably singelton) and register it in the container. An other solution would be, pass the needed service as parameter. If you realy want to go the route you current do, you need an [service locator](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/05/06/servicelocator-shim-for-net-core/), which is **not recommended**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use DI inside a static Method in Asp.net Core rc1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027206/how-to-use-di-inside-a-static-method-in-asp-net-core-rc1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't inject into a static constructor. You have a couple of options:

1.) Pass `ILogger` into the method, hopefully the calling code has it injected.

2.) Have a static property for `ILogger` on `ProfileContent` and then in your `Startup` file, in the `Configure` method, initialize it i.e.

```
ProfileContent.Logger = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILogger<ProfileContent>>();
```

then use `Logger` in your static method. Personally, I would go for option 1.

Comment: The only thing I could add to this is: 3) Get rid of the statics, with Singleton registrations in the DI, do this class really need to be static?

Comment: You preferred option 1.  Option 2. was hugely less code for me.  What's the reason for preferring option 1.?

Comment: Option 2 is the service locator anti pattern. It also  blackboxes the creation and assignment of Logger and as a general rule, I'm not a fan of static properties.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry a bit late but for interest for other folks who face this problem .. for static methods you can go with method injection. You cannot use constructor injection in a static class because the constructor of a static class cannot accept any parameters. Also, .net core doesn't allows property injection.
So, the only option that is available to us for static class is method injection. Consider the example below in which I am injecting Serilog.ILogger in the HandleModelBindingExceptions method.

```
        public static IMvcBuilder HandleModelBindingExceptions(this IMvcBuilder builder, ILogger logger)
    {
        var errorInfo = string.Empty;
        string methodName = "HandleModelBindingExceptions";

        builder.ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(option =>
          {
              //Lambda, Func delegate
              option.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = 
              context =>
              {
                  try
                  {
                  //Code to parse the errorResponse object 
                  
                  return new ObjectResult(errorResponse) { StatusCode = 400 };
              };
          });

        return builder;

    }
```

Comment: I was trying to implement something similar, but where I want to call builder.HandleModelBindingExceptions(), it wants me to pass an instance of ILogger (instead of resolving the dependancy)... any solution? Thanks! 

Comment: I think it's better to wrap my logic (in your case HandleModelBindingExceptions()) in a service and inject the required service into the ctor... This is the approach I'm going to take